# get coordinates of bone from the perspective of second bone in driver

Tags: rigging, bones, drivers, axis

I'd like to get the coordinates of one bone from the perspective of an other bone, i.e. figure out the x,y,z coordinates of bone A where the axis of the space is aligned with the rotation and location of bone B. The purpose of this is to drive different shape keys for when a bone is moved forwards or side wards relative to some other bone. It sounds like something like this ought to be possible in blender but so far i can not come up with a way of doing it.

If there happens to be some other elegant solution to the intended end-goal i'd be happy to take that one too.

Answer (score 0):

Although not in the same direction as i was originally thinking, one can get a good sense of which direction a bone is at using the following construction:

create a helper bone parented to and aligned with bone A, with a damped track constraint pointing to bone B. Now add the driver using the desired rotation of the helper bone  (e.g., X, Z) in [swing and Y twist mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/animation/drivers/drivers_panel.html#rotation-channel-modes) within local space. In this mode the angle is calculated as if the bone was first swung in the X,Z axis to align the bone, and then twisted in Y to match up the axis. This thus gives us an indication of the direction of bone B from the perspective of bone A without having to worry about any twisting around the Y axis of our helper bone.